# Keys not working after cleaning under key caps [macbook pro early 2008]

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, repair

I was using my father's computer while mine was in the shop, and thought I would clean out under the keyboard to be nice. Unfortunately, I managed to break his <kbd>D</kbd> key in the process.

Needless to say, he's very unhappy about it.

I'm not quite sure what the issue is - the "rubber spring" or cup is still there, but even when pressing on it with my finger, it does not register the key press. The only thing I can think of is that the rubber cup is not connected to the plastic layer underneath as it is with the other keys.

Any help would seriously be appreciated. I would prefer not to have to spend money on such an old machine.

Thanks.

Comment: what did you clean it with ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 - Just use a very small flathead screwdriver to pry up the keys, and then used a Q-Tip (dry) to scrape up the hair and stuff under the keys. No liquids used, at all.

Comment: you can buy a replacement key and try it.

Comment: Dust/grit might be under the cup. Offer to buy an external keyboard. Take it to a shop, they might be able to fix it cheap. You've said you want to save money, but reconsider this, as old Macs tend to hold their value if they're working.  Hindsight:  next time if you get a chance, get someone at a shop to do the cleaning.  I say this although I have cleaned many keyboards myself.  At a good shop, the shop will fix anything that goes wrong during cleaning.  At my favourite shop, they often take one look at my MacBook and ask me to let them clean it for free.  I'm lazy about cleaning it.

Comment: So here's the resolution - I bought a new top case off eBay for $20. He's using a bluetooth keyboard right now, and is "satisfied." I have cleaned this exact keyboard before, so I was very surprised to have broken it so badly.